Better to edit $VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim or add a script in $HOME/vimfiles/ftdetect?
Dead simple question: is it best practice to:

edit $VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim itself, or
add a script in $HOME/vimfiles/ftdetect?


Doing anything in $VIMRUNTIME is bad practice.

For sure not to edit $VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim since it is part of the distribution.
The alternatives you have are:

~/vimfiles/ftdetect/*.vim or
~/vimfiles/filetype.vim

I would first use ~/vimfiles/ftdetect/*.vim whenever possible.
But these scripts have no way to set the filetype if it set by the standard $VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim.
In that circumstance you can use ~/vimfiles/filetype.vim that is executed before $VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim.
